# Appium Port occupied

Tags: node.js, testing, automated-tests, appium, port

I'm trying to learn Appium but I'm already stuck in the beginning.
When I try to start Appium using the terminal I get an error message that looks like this:

```
Could not start REST http interface listener. The requested port may already be in use. Please make sure there is no other instance of this server running already.
Fatal Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 0.0.0.0:4723
```

So I tried to find out what instance is using that port using the statement `lsof -i :4723`
I found out there is a running node instance that uses this port so I tried to kill the instance with `kill -9 PID` . After I killed the instance I used `lsof -i :4723` again to see if it worked but the node instance was still there but with a new PID. I guess the kill was successful but node just immediately starts a new instance and occupies the port 4237.
Is there anyone who might have an idea what I can try or maybe knows a solution to this problem?

I found a small workaround which works for now but shouldn't be final. When I use `kill -9 PID | appium` it works because Appium occupies the port immediately after kill got executed.

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: How are you starting Appium? which is your configuration?

Comment: I just type appium in the terminal. I didn't change anything on the configuration so i guess it's just the normal configuration after the download.

Answer (score 0):

Try running appium on different port `appium -p 4725`

Comment: I tried that and it works. Does it matter which port I use to test my application or can I just use any port?

Comment: You can use any port which is free